# HOLD signal in 8085

Tags: dma, 8085

What happens to an 8085 system if a square wave signal of 1KHz frequency is applied to the HOLD signal of 8085?

The frequency of operation is 2MHz. 
Therefore, if the every 0.5ms, the HOLD pin goes HIGH and then goes low. Within the 0.5ms, The processor has 1000 T states, so the microprocessor would simply be held tri-stated for that long after it sends the HLDA signal and after 0.5ms automatically we'd resume normal operation? I'm unsure about my answer so please help me out.

Comment: To add to @TonyM's comment, at some point later the processor would assert HLDA and then relinquish the bus. On the other side, it would grab the bus back about a half-cycle after the HOLD goes inactive.

Comment: Be certain that master clock continues with 2 MHz while processor is holding...there is a maximum spec on clock period of 2 uS. And be aware that after HLDA goes hi, the CPU bus isn't fully tri-stated for a short period (about half a T-state).

Comment: @glen_geek, the minimum clock in a dynamic logic CPU is a general thing isn't it, it's not particular to bus mastership.

Comment: @TonyM Perhaps I'm pedantic, but that master clock is the one thing that must continue (along with DC Vcc), else the processor's internals drift into unknown states sometime during "hold". A static-logic CPU could get along with only Vcc.

Comment: @glen_geek, that's not what I'm saying though :-) The need to keep the clock constant is absolutely nothing to do with the HOLD/HOLDA bus mastership circuit. Nor is the OP more likely to start disabling said clock in bus hold than not. You have a point but it's not somehow connected to using HOLD.

Comment: @TonyM yes, yes we agree. Since OP mentioned 2MHz clk, so did I. Clk is not specifically related to hold condition. Your answer is very fine not mentioning clk - we all just assume that CPU is clking all the time, because that's what dynamic CPU's require.

Comment: Just as a note: looking back at the 8085A datasheet it appears to be limited to a clock cycle frequency between \$500\:\textrm{kHz}\$ and about \$3\:\textrm{MHz}\$ (the -2 version allowing up to \$5\:\textrm{MHz}\$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you describe is pretty much it.

The CPU would complete the current instruction before responding to the bus request. So the bus grant period may well be several clocks less than 1000 T states while that instruction's finished off first.